# Working with bytes and binary data in Python

Tags: python, binary, byte

Four consecutive bytes in a byte string together specify some value. However, only 7 bits in each byte are used; the most significant bit is always zero and therefore its ignored (that makes 28 bits altogether). So...

```
b"\x00\x00\x02\x01"
```

would be `000 0000` `000 0000` `000 0010` `000 0001`.

Or, for the sake of legibility, `10 000 0001`. That's the value the four bytes represent. But I want a decimal, so I do this:

```
>>> 0b100000001
257
```

I can work all that out myself, but how would I incorporate it into a program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use bitshifting and addition:

```
bytes = b"\x00\x00\x02\x01"
i = 0
for b in bytes:
    i <<= 7
    i += b     # Or use (b & 0x7f) if the last bit might not be zero.
print(i)
```

Result:

```
257
```

Comment: The 8th bit should be ignored, so it should be i += (b & 0x7f)

Comment: @miara: Thanks, you are right. I was assuming that it was zero.

Comment: Actually it is zero. Your unedited answer was right. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [bitarray module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray), you can do it a lot quicker for big numbers:

Benchmarks (factor 2.4x speedup!):

```
janus@Zeus /tmp % python3 -m timeit -s "import tst" "tst.tst(10000)" 
10 loops, best of 3: 251 msec per loop
janus@Zeus /tmp % python3 -m timeit -s "import tst" "tst.tst(100)"  
1000 loops, best of 3: 700 usec per loop
janus@Zeus /tmp % python3 -m timeit -s "import sevenbittoint, os" "sevenbittoint.sevenbittoint(os.urandom(10000))"
10 loops, best of 3: 73.7 msec per loop
janus@Zeus /tmp % python3 -m timeit -s "import quick, os" "quick.quick(os.urandom(10000))"                        
10 loops, best of 3: 179 msec per loop
```

quick.py (from Mark Byers):

```
def quick(bites):
  i = 0
  for b in bites:
    i <<= 7
    i += (b & 0x7f)
    #i += b
  return i
```

sevenbittoint.py:

```
import bitarray
import functools

def inttobitarray(x):
  a = bitarray.bitarray()
  a.frombytes(x.to_bytes(1,'big'))
  return a

def concatter(accumulator,thisitem):
  thisitem.pop(0)
  for i in thisitem.tolist():
    accumulator.append(i)
  return accumulator

def sevenbittoint(bajts):
  concatted = functools.reduce(concatter, map(inttobitarray, bajts), bitarray.bitarray())
  missingbits = 8 - len(concatted) % 8
  for i in range(missingbits): concatted.insert(0,0) # zeropad
  return int.from_bytes(concatted.tobytes(), byteorder='big')

def tst():
  num = 32768
  print(bin(num))
  print(sevenbittoint(num.to_bytes(2,'big')))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tst()
```

tst.py:

```
import os
import quick
import sevenbittoint

def tst(sz):
    bajts = os.urandom(sz)
  #for i in range(pow(2,16)):
  #  if i % pow(2,12) == 0: print(i)
  #  bajts = i.to_bytes(2, 'big')
    a = quick.quick(bajts)
    b = sevenbittoint.sevenbittoint(bajts)
    if a != b: raise Exception((i, bin(int.from_bytes(bajts,'big')), a, b))
```